# Sorting unique elements column-wise in a text-file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a tab delimited file like

```
chr1    4359314 4361314 Rp1 -
chr1    4492735 4494735 Sox17   -
chr1    4495330 4498354 Sox17,Sox17,Sox17,Sox17,Sox17,Sox17 -,-,-,-,-,-
chr1    4784698 4786739 Mrpl15,Mrpl15,Mrpl15,Mrpl15 -,-,-,-
chr1    4806788 4809237 Lypla1,Lypla1,Lypla1,RP24-426M1.3,Lypla1,Lypla1,Lypla1,Lypla1   +,+,+,+,+,+,+,+
chr1    4856814 4859038 Tcea1,Tcea1 +,+
chr1    5017735 5020539 Rgs20,Rgs20,Rgs20   -,-,-
chr1    5069018 5071285 Atp6v1h,Rgs20,Rgs20 +,-,-
chr1    5082080 5084154 Atp6v1h,Atp6v1h,Atp6v1h,Atp6v1h +,+,+,+
chr1    5587493 5589941 Oprk1,Oprk1,Oprk1   +,+,+
```

I want to filter out by column 5, only the lines which can have any amount and order of "+" or "-" meaning multiple instances per line like +,-,+ or -,-,+ or +,+,+,+,- etc but should be mixed not cases like -,- or -,-,-,- or +,+,+

Output

```
chr1    5069018 5071285 Atp6v1h,Rgs20,Rgs20 +,-,-
```

I tried using extended grep like

```
cut -f5 file | egrep '(+.*-)|(-.*+)' | head
```

but I cant make it work for multiple matches per line, any order.
Can anyone suggest a minimalist way(regex/one-liner) to do it, without specifying different order. (sed/awk preferred)

Brings me to another question. Can I `sort -u` but columnwise

```
cut -f5 file | tr ',' '\t'| sort -uk1???
```

Input

```
-
-
-,-,-,-,-,-
-,-,-,-
+,+,+,+,+,+,+,+
+,+
-,-,-
+,-,-
+,+,+,+
+,+,+
```

Output:

```
-
-
-
-
+
+
-
+-
+
+
```

Comment: "only the lines which can have any amount and order of + or - but should be mixed." is a bit unclear. Could you give a better explanation to this as it seems to be the key information here?

Comment: I edited my question, essentially this
I want to filter out by column 5, only the lines which can have any amount and order of "+" or "-" meaning multiple instances per line like +,-,+ or -,-,+ or +,+,+,+,- etc but should be mixed not cases like -,- or -,-,-,- or +,+,+

Comment: I think you mean rows, not columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '$5 !~ /^(\+,)*\+$/ && $5 !~ /^(-,)*\-$/' file
```

It checks whether `$5` (column 5)  contains a sequence of `+,..,+` or a sequence of `-,..,-`. If not, the line gets printed.

Output:

```
chr1    5069018 5071285 Atp6v1h,Rgs20,Rgs20 +,-,-
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect. Can you explain a bit what is  `!~` in the start.
Can you additionally comment on how can we count the no. of + and - per row like
`- 1
- 1
+ 1 - 2`  etc

Comment: @SukhdeepSingh The `!~` means *not match*. If we count the `+` and `-`, What do you expect the output should look like?

Comment: Ah ok, Output I tried to write in the above comment but in column format.
So, match (+ or -) followed by the number (of times match)

`- 1 
+ 1 
+,- 1,2 (this would be the answer of the above command you wrote)`
Sorry, I am unable to write the output in tabular format. The above three lines are three rows.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you add the expected output of that to the question?